# prevent calling function twice in an IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I prevent from this function executing twice, will it execute twice or does mysql optimize this?

```
IF(CheckTest(node.id, 1) == 0, NULL, CheckTest(node.id, 1)) as val
```

The problem I can't return NULL from the function itself because the return value is a VARCHAR so even if it's empty set that gets converted back to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @joachim-isaksson pointed out, MySql seems not to optimize it. So you could use this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (@check:=CheckTest(node.id, 1)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @check END as val
```

Comment: Ah that looks nice thank you! although I found out my problem, even though the function returns a varchar I can still set it to null, what I had to do is change the SET returnVar to NULL before executing and returning, previously it was set to 0 which is what was returned and I erroneously thought it was due to the empty set.

Comment: Just as a side note, MySQL doesn't seem to optimize it, at least not when the function has side effects; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4a07/7

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks for the fiddle and for the tests... i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
set @myvar := CheckTest(node.id, 1);
select if(@myvar == 0, NULL, @myvar) as val;
```

Comment: how exactly do I integrate that in my SELECT query because node.id is retrieved as part of the query it's in.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think that MySQL will optimize this, you should use a profiler to see what is happening. Run your query through SQLyog or similar.

There is another way to solve this kind of double-executions.

First, create a temporary table and populate it with records which satisfy the CheckTest condition.

Then, in the main query, make a join with this table. This way, the test will be executed exactly once for each record.